# How i can call uipath robot using wso2 using rest api?

Tags: rest, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

Currently we are scheduling our robots using windows task manager. But in future we have to schedule our robots via wso2.Is it important to have an orchestrator? can we do without orchestrator ,is any alternate way?
And if not then how to do using orchestrator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be over the orchestator. For example you can create CRON Triggers https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/managing-triggers.

But you can do it also without orchestrator. See:
https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-run-attended-bot-without-orchestrator/87417/2